# How can I create if else for formData in react?

Tags: reactjs, form-data

I'm trying to achieve if user dont need add avatar but still create a team but i am having problem that if user don't add avatar in form it will cause an error saying `file: undefined`

Here is my following code for handleSubmit:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // upload image to server
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageSelected.raw);

    const pictureUrl = await axios.post(
      "/api/v1/teams/upload/image",
      formData,
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      }
    );

    const teamAvatar = pictureUrl.data.data.imageUrl;

    // after upload image to server get image data and send it to create team function
    const payload = { title, mission, isSearchable, teamAvatar };
    // Send post request for signup
    const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/teams/team", payload);

    // If no validation errors were found
    if (res.data.validationErrors === undefined) {
      // Clear any errors
      setErrorsArr([]);
      // Hide the errors component
      setShowErrors(false);
      // Toggle the modal
      toggleModal();
      // Go to team management page
      NextRouter.push(`/team/${res.data}`);
      // console.log("payload", payload);
    } else {
      // Set errors
      setErrorsArr(res.data.validationErrors.errors);
      // Show the errors component
      setShowErrors(true);
    }
  };
```

How can I create if else statement for formData that help user don't need to add avatar but still can create a team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if(imageSelected){
 formData.append("file", imageSelected.raw);
}
```